# How to copy text from tmux to clipboard in Mac OS Monterey with terminal app

Tags: macos, terminal, tmux

I am using Tmux version 3.2a. I used this [tutorial](https://www.rockyourcode.com/copy-and-paste-in-tmux/) and many more to enable this functionality but couldn't achieve it so far.

The main problem is when I copy the following code to the tmux config,

```
bind -T copy-mode-vi v send -X begin-selection
bind -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "pbcopy"
bind P paste-buffer
bind -T copy-mode-vi MouseDragEnd1Pane send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "pbcopy"
```

and get to the copy mode with `ctrl+b` and then `ctrl+[`, and press `v` to get into to the visual mode, nothing happens.

My final tmux config is

```
set-option -g mouse on
setw -g mode-keys vi
set-option -s set-clipboard off
bind P paste-buffer
bind -T copy-mode-vi v send -X begin-selection
bind -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "pbcopy"
bind -T copy-mode-vi MouseDragEnd1Pane send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "pbcopy"
```

I can not use normal v bindings like `u` and `d` for scrolling. I use the terminal app that comes with Mac OS Monterey.

The closest I come was to hold down the `fn` button and simply select the text. This works to some extent but has a major problem. When I scroll the terminal output, it does not show anything above as understandable from the figure hopefully.

[image]

The empty part occurs when I scroll up.

Comment: For the record, with the exact settings, iTerm app worked like a charm but I am still curious about this.